# This code is not working properly. It says that android application closed down unexpectedly

Tags: android

Check this code
This code is not working properly. It says that android application closed down unexpectedly.
trying to use bluetoothadapter class here but not working on a device.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //On = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


}

public void on(View view){
    BluetoothAdapter mblue = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 

    if(!mblue.isEnabled())
    {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Bluetooth Enabled!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    }

    else{
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Already On!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        }
 }
```

Comment: log from LogCat with exception stack trace

Comment: Did you set permission for this?

Comment: No.. I am trying this for the first time and it seems very confusing to me.

Comment: I copied another code which is working properly but when I implemented it on my own its not working.

Comment: did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @silverback how can we extract log from LogCat ?

Comment: @Rami no.. Let me try

Comment: You are welcome. You must thank @Suvitruf also, he was the first to mention that!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it's correct. I'm pretty sure that your problem is related to the fact that you didn't add to AndroidManifest.xml the permissions for bluetooth.
Just add this line to manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>`